# В каких случаях класс, реализованный полностью в заголовочном файле, может вызвать ошибку?

Tags: c++, c++11

Несколько раз встречался с такой ситуацией, когда класс, целиком реализованный в заголовочном файле, вызывал ошибки во время исполнения.

Но стоит разделить класс на два файла `.h` и `.cpp`, как ошибки сразу исчезают.

Пытался специально воспроизвести такую ошибку, но пока что не получилось.

Из-за чего могут появляться такие ошибки?

Comment: Реализован он либо со статическими членами-данными, либо, что вероятнее, с реализацией методов не inline (не в теле класса), а вне его. И получается нарушение - одна и та же сущность (функция, переменная) оказывается дважды определенной...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Как и сказал @Harry первая ошибка это мульти определение. Глобальные переменные в этих заголовках вызывают самую большую проблему. Так же проблемой станет определение функции не при декларации. При этом проблема появляется ни сразу, а как только этот хейдер будет подключён в более чем один файл. Но самая бесящая ошибка которая может произойти это рекурсивный инклуд. Может показаться что "ну я же не дурак я не буду подключать файл к файлу в котором уже подключён этот файл" но не обязательно иметь рекурсивный инклуд напрямую. Это порождает forward declaration и бывает найти эту самую рекурсию не просто.

Реализовывать класс в заголовочном файле плохая идея если только это не шаблоны или этот файл не генерится какой нибудь тулзой.